# Function to Change "List" objects into "numerics"

Tags: r, function

I have a matrix containing several "list" vector. I would like to transform them into numerics.
I have read that I should use as.numeric(x) - but since I have several values I would like to use a function which goes through my matrix and checks each vector of the matrix if it is a list and returns it as a numeric.

I have thought I could use something like:

```
if 
typeof(matrix$vector1)=="list"
```

`then 
as.numeric(matrix$vector1)`

Can anybody help me out as how to create such a function?
I'd appreciate any kind of help!

Kind regards,

Comment: Did you try `unlist`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sven. I did just now try to use "unlist", however that did not help. The typeof(vector) remains "list".

Comment: How did it get that way in the first place? This is one of those questions where it feels like the right answer is to fix some earlier step.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for your feedback. I did a group work and the teammate before me actually did the task and gave it to me as a list. That's why I cannot fix the code before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if (is.list(matrix$vector1)) sapply(matrix$vector1,as.numeric)
```

`is.list` will check whether input is list, if TRUE then `sapply` will 'apply' the function as.numeric to every element of the list

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vivek. Yes that is exactly what I was looking for thanks! One follow-up question though if I may: How can I automatically read out my headers, since my headers have completly different names (such as Male, Age, ID, etc.,...)

Comment: try this : `if (is.list(matrix$vector1)) numeric.list<-sapply(matrix$vector1,as.numeric); names(numeric.list)<-names(matrix$vector1)`